# Localization and field of fractions of an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, localization

I have searched the site, but there is a lot of confusion regarding this topic, so I try to be as clear as possible.

Let $R$ be an integral domain and denote with $K(R)$ the field of fractions of $R$.

Now, let $S\subseteq R$, $0\notin S$, any multiplicatively closed subset of $R$.

Let $S^{-1}R$ be the localization of $R$ at $S$. Suppose that $S^{-1}R$ is a integral domain.

Is the following true or false?

> $$K(R)\cong K(S^{-1}R)$$

Can this isomorphism be derived from the universal property of localization? If so, how can I proceed strictly?

Comment: It is true, that once you've made all the nonzero elements of integral domain $R$ invertible, you've subsumed all the localizations of $R$.  The key is that in a natural way $R\subset K(R)$, and localization (in the absence of zero divisors) preserves inclusion.  Perhaps you could sketch the "universal property" you have in mind, to see if it suffices to adduce these facts.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975575/isomorphism-of-ring-localized-twice-atiyah-macdonald-exercise-3-3) or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3591963/22912)